# Show hidden asp.net control via jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden control (an asp.net label) and want to show it when a user clicks a button.

Here is the hidden control

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCityRequired" visible="False" runat="server" Text="Required if Country  State are selected"></asp:Label>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
function showLabel()
{
    $("#lblCityRequired").show();
}

function hideLabel()
{
    $("#lblCityRequired").hide();
}
```

This only works when the label's visibility is not set to false. However I want the form to start up hiding the message. Is there something I am doing wrong? Should I just create a javascript function that starts up hiding the label via javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when the control is set to false, it is not rendered in the client. you can try setting a display:none on the control to make it work.

Comment: Adding style attribute to the tag `style="display:none"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it initally when dom is ready:

```
 $(function(){
     hideLabel();
 })
```

Or, you can use css:

```
 <style>#lblCityRequired{display:none;}</style>
```